# How to use swap memory in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to use swap memory in my dockerized application because sometimes the container's memory consumption exceeds the limit and they get crashed.

I am using the below configuration in docker-compose which produces an error

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.app1-cnn.deploy.resources.reservations value Additional properties are not allowed ('memory-swap' was unexpected)
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.3"             

services:

  app-cnn:
    build: ./app
    image: "app-cnn"
    restart: always
    container_name: app-cnn
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 3G
        reservations:
          memory-swap: 6G
```

Comment: The `deploy:` block is only used in Docker Swarm; are you using that, or just native single-host Docker?  If your host system has swap enabled then you shouldn't have to do anything special for a container process to use it.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am using Docker Swarm

Comment: @DavidMaze, I can confirm `deploy:` is available without Swarm; see changes with `docker stats`. I have verified Swarm mode with `docker info --format '{{.Swarm.ControlAvailable}}'` which outputs `false`. More info about `deploy:` here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#deploy

Answer (score 7):

refer to https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#memswap_limit

from my test result by default memswap is double of the memory size. if you need more, use memswap_limit to overwrite it.

have to say the structure is wierd somehow, not sure why it is designed like that. Anyway, below configuration works for me.

```yaml
...
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 512M
        reservations:
          memory: 128M
    memswap_limit: 6G
```